# Load multiple Autodesk Inventor AddIns

Tags: api, load, add-in, autodesk-inventor

I've got two Inventor addins which are both based on the same common custom library. When loading one addin via its .addin file, everything works fine. When using both .addin files, only one addin is loaded on startup, the other one has to be loaded manually (allthough it is visibile in the AppManager) and then works fine as well. The constructor of the second addin is not called, so its method activate() can't be fired.
I checked the .addin files, the guids, everything seems to be ok. It should be ok, otherwise the loading wouldn't do with the single .addin files though.
Any help or hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying, testing and searching: classId and clientId have to be the same in order to have working functionality regarding automatic loading of several addins (at least in Inventor 2020 and 2021).